# How to use python to run a list from one file through another script

Tags: python, linux, bash, perl

Alright, so I am being tasked with a large task of auditing the use of our IPs in my office because we are running low. So I am trying to write a basic script that takes a list of the IPs I need to verify , and tun them against another script that verifies the IP's use. I have it working in Bash, but I want to use Python so that I can make some adjustments the way I like.

So I have a file called "iprange" and I have a perl file a former coworker made that no longer works here, and it takes an IP and checks it, verifies what is using it, and then outputs it back. Here is example of what "works" for me in Bash.

```
cat iprange | xargs -I % checkIP.pl -s % > ipresults.txt 2>&1
```

The problem is, This gives me an output that looks like this.

```
"This IP is free"
"This IP is free"
"This IP is used by XPNSE43525"
```

There are two problems. 1) There are thousands of IPs, so I need to find a way to have it so it looks more like this.

```
10.4.8.5
"This IP is free"
```

OR

```
checkIP.pl -s 10.4.8.5
"This IP is free"
```

Since this does not seem possible with bash, I am hoping to get this hammered out with Python. But have no idea how to get python to launch the script and output it the same way I do with bash.

Comment: Sounds like you need to modify the Perl script.

Comment: The script takes an input of an IP and tells me if its in use... What I am trying to do is run another script that will run a list of IPs through the perl script and output them one by one. I cant really modify the perl script to grab from the files, because normally its only use is for individual prompt from a user.

Answer (score 1):

You could always write a small wrapper script that is invoked by xargs and which in turn displays the IP address and then invokes `checkIP.pl`.

checkIP.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
echo -n "$1 : "
checkIP.pl -s $*
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
cat iprange | xargs -I % checkIP.sh % > ipresults.txt 2>&1
```

and expect to see output like this:

```
10.4.8.5 : This IP is free
10.1.1.1 : This IP is free
192.168.1.1 : This IP is used by XPNSE43525
8.8.8.8 : This IP is used by Google DNS
```

Answer (score 0):

What @squiguy said is correct. You probably need to modify the PERL script.

```
grep "This IP is free" checkIP.pl
grep "This IP is used by" checkIP.pl
```

Find the lines in the file where the lines are on in the script by running a couple of greps

Then assuming the script used 'Getopt::Std qw(getopts);' the variable that the -s' parameter should be attached to is "$opt_s"

Change the lines to

```
"$opt_s: This IP is free"
"$opt_s: This IP is used by"
```